How to make ssh return immediately after running background job
When I run on linux-system/bash:
sleep 10 &

I get bash prompt immediately.
But when I run:
ssh linux-system 'sleep 10 &'

I wait 10 seconds.
Two questions:

Can I find explanation in ssh/bash documentation ?

By changing context/configuration, can we make ssh to return immediately, without changing the command sleep 10 & itself? for example :


ssh linux-system 'change-bash-configuration; sleep 10 &'

or
ssh -some-ssh-options linux-system 'sleep 10 &'

Update 1
We can use ssh -f to get the prompt, but a background ssh process still waits for remote process to finish. So my questions remain.
Update 2
To clarify, I want local ssh process to terminate (not waiting for 10 seconds in the background) after starting remote job in the background.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

According to the ssh man page

The session terminates when the command or shell on the remote machine
exits and all X11 and TCP connections have been closed.

The reason ssh doesn't exit right away is because the remote command still has stdin, stdout, stderr open.  If you close them, it should return immediately.
ssh localhost "sleep 10 < /dev/null &> /dev/null &"

This replaces stdin, stdout, and stderr for sleep.  Bash still has those open.  But since sleep is now in the background, since this is not an interactive bash shell, it leaves bash with nothing left to do and it exits, closing the connections that the remote sshd provided for stdin, stdout, and stderr.   Since at that point there are no open connections for ssh, it can close the ssh session and exit.
To extend this example a bit, if you ran
ssh -X localhost "(xclock & sleep 1) < /dev/null &> /dev/null"

then ssh would establish an X11 tunnel which xclock would then open a connection through.  (The sleep is needed to give xclock time to start before bash exits.)  Bash would then exit, but the X11 connection would persist and ssh would not exit.  If you killed ssh, the xclock would lose its connection through the tunnel and the window would close.  If instead you close or kill the xclock window itself, xclock will close the X11 connection, and since that's the last connection, ssh would then exit.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You probably don’t need the < /dev/null, since background (asynchronous) processes get their stdin redirected to /dev/null by default.

It is needed unless you use -f or -n at least with older versions of ssh and commands that might try to take input.

The behavior is the same, actually. What happens is that you are sending the sleep to the background on the remote machine, but you are not sending the ssh command to the background on your local machine. So the local machine waits for the ssh to finish, and the ssh waits for the sleep to finish.
If you want to get your local prompt back immediately, you can send the ssh to the background:
ssh linux-system 'sleep 10' &

However, this will likely hit another issue, so if this is the behavior you want, use -f:
ssh -f linux-system 'sleep 10'

Or make sure no input goes to the ssh command from the terminal with
ssh linux-system 'sleep 10' </dev/null

If you want the command to continue on the remote server, even if you close your local terminal, you can use nohup:
ssh linux-system 'nohup sleep 10 &' </dev/null &

or
ssh -f linux-system 'nohup sleep 10 &' </dev/null &

As for where this is documented, it is unlikely to be explicitly mentioned, this isn't a special feature or anything, it is simply that your original version wasn't sending the ssh to the background.

I don't want to start ssh in background, but make it to terminate.

@Philippe I don't understand what that means. Can you clarify?

@Philippe You said before that you just wanted to understand, not that you wanted to have any particular effect.  Please update your question with what you want.

For example, why there is no difference between ssh linux-system 'sleep 10' and ssh linux-system 'sleep 10 &' ?

@Philippe: Terdon explained the difference between those two in this answer.

@Philippe there is. The second runs ssh on the remote server in the background, while the first runs ssh on the remote server in the foreground. However, both run on the foreground on your local machine so you see the same behavior. Anything inside the ' ' only applies to the remote server and doesn't affect your local machine.

I understand that. When I said no difference, I meant I wait 10 seconds in both cases.

@Philippe well yes, exactly. What else would you expect? In both cases, you are running a command on the local machine (ssh) and not sending it to the background, so the shell will wait until the command finishes before returning control and giving you your prompt back. If you want to get control back immediately, use ssh 'command' & or ssh -f 'command'. You seem to be expecting something different but what exactly that is isn't obvious.

I want ssh to terminate (not to run in the background waiting for 10 seconds) after starting remote job in the background.

@Philippe then please say that in your question. Sounds like you should be using screen or tmux. Ideally, also explain why you want this because that will help us understand hat you really need. Why do you not want to have the ssh running? The resources it consumes are negligible, so is it that you want to be able to turn off your local machine and leave the command running remotely? If so, that's what screen and tmux are for.

I know screen or tmux can do the job and I used them before. Again, it's more to understand that why sleep 10 & holds the bash process to wait and how to get around it.

Hmm. I wonder. @Philippe, are you effectively asking about the exact gory details of when SSH decides to cut the connection and exit the client? And how that compares to running a task in the background in the shell? I mean, does the connection end when all copies of the relevant fds are closed on the server, or does the ssh daemon watch for its child processes, or the terminal-related thingies like sessions and process groups or...  (I don't know the answer directly.)

@Philippe that's what I explain in the answer: it isn't sleep 10 & that holds it, it is any command, because the & there only applies to the remote server. When you do ssh remote 'command &', the command is sent to the background on the remote, but the local machine only knows about the ssh, the only thing running locally, and that has not been sent to the background. You would need ssh 'command &' & to send the local to the background as well.

the man page for the SSH client says "The session terminates when the command or shell on the remote machine exits and all X11 and TCP connections have been closed." and usually, it returns with the exit status of the process it launched, so it has to wait for at least that. Which still doesn't preclude tricks to launch grandchild process which the server-side SSH process doesn't see, and which could stay running remotely. (Things that e.g. screen needs to do to work.)

This doesn't even work for me.  I get "stopped" .   This answer is actually wrong.

@user10489 ah, sorry, forgot about that. See updated answer and, better, SSH connections running in the background don't exit if multiple connections have been started by the same shell.

@ilkkachu Now my question is : why with ssh localhost "sleep 10 < /dev/null >& /dev/null &" , ssh terminates immediately, but not with ssh localhost "sleep 10 &" ? Can we find explanation in the documentation ?

@Philippe please read the answer I link to in my answer here.

I did take a look, but I don't think it's relevant to my question.

@Philippe, I don't think the man page at least explicitly says that, but it looks like the SSH process on the remote waits for the stdin/etc. fds of the remote shell to close, not just for the command itself to exit. Which makes sense, because it helps catch any lingering child processes the initial command (shell) might have started.

@ilkkachu You are right, that makes perfect sense.
